# Optimize Cloud Datastore NDB query to reduce read operation counts

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

After running my GAE app for 1 week, I got 30 millions count and I have to pay 23.31 usd :(

```
Cloud Datastore Read Ops Japan  30,245,982.00 Count $23.31
```

Please help me to optimize queries.
In my app, I have a lot of queries, mainly to check **if entity does not exist, then do something**

```
tweet_db_qry = model.PopularTweet.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('twaccount_key') == twaccount_db.key).filter(ndb.GenericProperty('originaltweetid') == tweetid)  
if tweet_db_qry.count() == 0:
```

I plan to change it to:

```
tweet_db = model.PopularTweet.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('twaccount_key') == twaccount_db.key).filter(ndb.GenericProperty('originaltweetid') == tweetid).get(keys_only=True)  
if tweet_db is None:
```

Comment: As I see it, you will get charged equally in both of your options. The `query().filter([...])` operation is what you are being charged for and they are the same. I have submitted an answer that is not specific for your problem but I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Cloud Datastore [best practices documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices) to see if any of the recommendations apply to your case. The sections about API and queries have suggestions that can optimize the latency and the cost of your application.

Also, if you are worried about charges into your billing account, you can [set up alerts and budgets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#managing_billing) for your GCP project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use a [projection query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries).  Using a projection query will mean that you are only charged for the query instead of reading the full entity results for the query.  You could also use fetch(limit=1) on your query object to limit the number of reads on your query to 1 entity.

Comment: Thanks. I think fetch(limit=1) is same as get(). And I query key only, so I try get(keys_only=True). And I use get() to retrieve the 1st entity. Does my code mean I read the full entity before retrieve the 1st entity?

Comment: keys_only is a special case of a projection query.  So for keys_only or the projection query you'll be charged for the query, but not the query and the entity read.